# Running two .ajax()

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-post

As title, I have two ajax() has to go through but in condition that A ajax has to be go through in order to do B ajax.

A ajax as in <<=== .ajaxFileupload()

B ajax as in <<=== .ajax()

Any recommend to do the condition so that A must be success in order to do B ?? or any method that I shall implement ?

To alex:

u mean something like this ??

```
$.ajaxFileUpload({
   .....
   .....
   success:function(data){
           $.ajax({


           });

   }

});
```

Comment: I'm really not understanding your question, could you think of a way to reword it? Perhaps have some sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call B inside of the success handler for A..

```
$.ajaxA({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
      $.ajaxB....
  }
});
```

[jQuery Ajax API docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more info on the success method.

Comment: Rick u mean something like above ??

Comment: Yes... depending on the conditions for running B you can do the success handler or the complete handler (which will get called everytime, success or failure) like @alex mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

On the `complete` callback of *A ajax*, make the *B ajax call*.

Comment: alex u mean something like what I do in  above ?

Comment: @Eric Yes. Though it depends if you want to run it on error/success or both. The above will do both.